# Formatting values on the y axis in a dc.js / d3 chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I am trying to shorten the values on my Y axis, currently they are appearing as so:

[image: Example]

While I can play around with the padding, I would like the Y axis to be displayed in this manner:

100,000 = 100k
200,000 = 200k

etc etc

Attached is my code.

```
var paidSubChart = dc.lineChart("chart1")
.width(450)
.height(300)
.elasticX(true)
.x(d3.scale.linear().domain([-30,N]))
.elasticY(true)
.brushOn(false)
.yAxisLabel("Paid Subs")
.xAxisLabel("Days Since Launch")
.dimension(dayCountDimension)
.group(paidSubGroup);

var expansionActChart = dc.lineChart("chart2")
.width(450)
.height(300)
.elasticX(true)
.x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0,N]))
.elasticY(true)
.brushOn(false)
.yAxisLabel("Paid Subs")
.xAxisLabel("Days Since Launch")
.dimension(dayCountDimension)
.group(expActGroup);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The axes in dc.js are provided by d3.js.

I think you're looking for

```
chart.yAxis().tickFormat(d3.format('.3s'))
```

which calls [d3.axis.tickFormat](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Axes.md#tickFormat) and uses [d3.format](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Formatting.md#d3_format)'s "SI prefix".

Note: it's best to keep axis manipulation in a separate statement because [stuff breaks if you try to chain other dc.js chart commands after a `yAxis` command](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#why-does-everything-break-after-a-call-to-xaxis-or-yaxis).